# How do I extend ComboBoxBase and make a custom control

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I'm Using JavaFX. My dilemma is I'm trying to create a custom popup control like DatePicker or ColorPicker. I've tried creating my little widget, loading it into a Pane and putting that pane in a ComboBox but every time I clicked on it, the combobox would just collapse. I've seen something like it being done when someone made a fontpicker. I saw comboboxbasebehavior in the fontpicker project on github, yet I didn't see it in the Java documentation. I'm semi-new to this so I apologize if this question is apparently simple. I just need to know what I need to do.

```
     public void initialize(){

cal = new CalendarModel();
monthLabel.setText(cal.getMonth());
loadCalendarDate();
currentDateLabel.setText(cal.getToday().toString());
DecadeChooserController dcc = new DecadeChooserController (new CalendarModel());
loadDecadeContentPane();
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
```

}

// the loadDecadeContentPane method

```
public void loadDecadeContentPane(){    
Pane contentPane = new Pane();

        try {
            contentPane =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/DecadeChooser.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        comboBox.getItems().add(contentPane);
 }
```

Comment: welcome to SO!  can you include a snippet of your code from your first attempt?  might help focus answers.  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean by "putting that pane IN combo box"? Is it, whenever you choose some combo box, your popup should be showed?

Comment: Did you override [`createDefaultSkin`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html#createDefaultSkin--) to return a custom [`ComboBoxPopupControl`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/skin/ComboBoxPopupControl.html)?

Comment: no I did not fabian. Thank you for that tip though